# Ratios of polynomials and derivatives under a certain functional

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n>2$, with roots $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ (including multiplicities). Let $m$ be a positive even integer. Define the following mapping
$$V_m(p)=\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(x_i-x_j)^m.$$

> **QUESTION.** For $\deg p(x)=n>2$ and $p'(x)$ its derivative, can you express
> $$\frac{V_m(p)}{V_m(p')}$$
> as a function of $m$ and $n$ alone?

**Remark.** Prompted by Fedor's questions, as a showcase I just computed (not proved) that
$$\frac{V_2(p)}{V_2(p')}=\frac{n^2}{(n-1)(n-2)}.$$

Comment: The $m=2$ case was here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309340/roots-and-relation-between-polynomials-and-their-derivatives

Comment: Ah, I read $\sum$ as a product, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a [SageMath code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx9jrFuwkAQRPv7ipFSsBsMxJRILnGHlEskNxGJHDis03n3osMu_Pc54qB02W6kN2_WWkWFOrWnwUetvevP9Bz7SaP4tn_x2pG1BRa6YDY31Fpdd06JzSGn10nEDcmf6lF_DNeMK68lzoKM7f_BXO_E6dCmKYPGnN0FDQnv8HcPaD6EvtjcQsqu6ygEWpX8HvCIT_87JEXgnA9vsgpFOOISEwK8IrXaOSoLyGazxRIl4y5bViDNprl3vA-G6mkG3DAmxZ5Sfq6hLX8DGQJUpQ==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) that provides a function `V(m)` computing $V_m(p)$ in terms of elementary symmetric functions of $x_1,\dots,x_n$ (i.e. coefficients of $p$).

For example, if $p(x) = x^n - e_1 x^{n-1} + e_2 x^{n-2} + \dots$, then
$$V_2(p) = (n-1)e_1^2 - 2n e_2,$$
$$V_4(p) = (n-1) e_1^4 - 4n e_2 e_1^2 + (2n+12)e_2^2 + (4n-12) e_3 e_1 - 4n e_4,$$
and so on.

From these expressions a proof for $m=2$ follows instantly. However, for larger $m$ the ratio $\frac{V_m(p)}{V_m(p')}$ does not appear to be a function of $n$, which I've tested computationally for $m$ up to $20$.

Comment: I find it rather interesting that it is a constant for $n=3$ and $m=4$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Indeed, but this does not extend to larger $m$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: At dxdy.ru it was suggested that the case $n=3$ and $m=4$ reduces to $m=2$ via the identity: $$(a-b)^4+(a-c)^4+(b-c)^4 = \frac12\left((a-b)^2+(a-c)^2+(b-c)^2\right)^2.$$

Comment: yes, it is equivalent, cf. my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If this were true, $V_m(p)/V_m(p'')=(V_m(p)/V_m(p'))\times(V_m(p')/V_m(p''))$ also would depend only on $m$ and $n=\deg p$, and so on, until we get $V_m(p)/V_m(p^{(n-2)})$. We have $$V_m(p^{(n-2)})=V_m\left(\frac{n!}2x^2-(n-1)!\left(\sum x_i\right)x+(n-2)!\sum_{i<j} x_ix_j\right)=c_{nm}\left((n-1)\left(\sum x_i\right)^2-2n\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j\right)^{m/2}=\tilde{c}_{nm} V_2(p)^{m/2}.$$
So if this were true, we would have $V_m(p)=C_{nm} (V_2(p))^{m/2}$. This is false already for $n=m=4$: if all the roots of $p$ are 0's and 1's, we have $V_4=V_2$, but $V_2^2/V_4=V_2$ is not fixed.